# How to properly convert an unsigned char array into an uint32_t

Tags: c, casting

So, I'm trying to convert an array of `unsigned char`s into an `uint32_t`, but keep getting different results each time:

```
unsigned char buffer[] = {0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};;
uint32_t num = (uint32_t*)&buffer;
```

Now, I keep getting this warning:

> warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast

When I change `num` to `*num` i don't get that warning, but that's not actually the real problem (**UPDATE:** well, those might be related now that I think of it.), because *every time I run the code there is different results*. Secondly the `num`, once it's cast properly, should be `128`, but If I need to change the endianness of the buffer I could manage to do that myself, *I think*.

Thanks!

Comment: the above example you are setting num to the address of the buffer array. You should  use
 `uint32_t num = *(uint32_t*)buffer; `
to get to the number.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Did you try this ?

```
num = (uint32_t)buffer[0] << 24 |
      (uint32_t)buffer[1] << 16 |
      (uint32_t)buffer[2] << 8  |
      (uint32_t)buffer[3];
```

This way you control endianness and whatnot.

It's really not safe to cast a `char` pointer and interpret it as anything bigger. Some machines expect pointers to integers to be aligned.

Comment: +1, this is the sane and portable way of doing this. Assuming `buffer` holds a `uint32_t` in big-endian format, of course, but the OP didn't specify that.

Comment: Won't this cause problems if you are casting buffer[i], an 8-bit quantity, to a uint32_t?

Comment: @Foo Bah: No, there is nothing wrong with converting an `unsigned char` to `uint32_t` - the latter type must necessarily be at least as large as the former, so the value will be unchanged.

Answer (score 11):

cnicutar's answer is the best assuming you want a particular fixed endianness. If you want host endian, try:

```
uint32_t num;
memcpy(&num, buffer, 4);
```

or apply `ntohl` to cnicutar's answer. Any method based on type punning is wrong and dangerous.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for and trying to do with cast operator!

Answer (score 3):

First, you want to say `num = *(uint32_t *)&buffer`

To change endianness, you can use a call like bswap_32 (in linux, byteswap.h) or OSSwapInt64 (in osx, libkern/OSByteOrder.h)

Comment: ... which yields undefined behavior due to alignment problems; on some RISC processors, this may crash the program.

Comment: @larsmans without explicitly forcing a single-character packing scheme, won't the static array be correctly aligned?

Comment: That's not guaranteed by the C standard. In fact, I believe your example violates the aliasing rule as well, meaning that it may break due to optimizations even when the buffer is correctly aligned.

Comment: This is the traditional way to do it, but it's invalid C.

Answer (score 1):

The warning was issued because `&buffer` yields a pointer to pointer. Even without the reference operator `&` the warning wouldn't have disappeared because the casting changes only the pointer type. The pointer is further converted to integer and therefore the warning.

If endianness is not important, the obvious solution seems to me

```
unsigned char buffer[] = {0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
uint32_t num = *(uint32_t *)buffer;
```

which means dereferencing the casted pointer to the char array.

Comment: This is doubly-broken.  First, given `unsigned char buffer[]`, `uint32_t num = *(uint32_t *)buffer;` [violates strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and is thus undefined behavior.  It also can violate any alignment restrictions of [**6.3.2.3 Pointers**, paragraph 7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7): "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @AndrewHenle can you please further elaborate on why this violates strict aliasing? I am having trouble understanding aliasing. Aren't uint8_t and uint32_t compatible types?

Comment: @earthling Strict aliasing in C or C++ (they're very close if not actually identical in the way this is interpreted) is pretty simple - you can't refer to a memory location as a type different from what it actually is - except that you can refer to anything as an array of `[[un]signed] char`.  Breaking that rule - as done here by referring to an `unsigned char` array as a `uin32_t` - violates strict aliasing as the arrays is not a `uint32_t`, so it invokes UB.  See [**What is the strict aliasing rule?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) for a LOT more

Comment: (cont) The portable solution is to use `memcpy()` - as in `memcpy(&num, buffer, sizeof(num));`  Any decent optimizing compiler will optimize out the `memcpy()` and replace it with a suitable direct assignment that won't break things.  The *compiler* is allowed to do that, if your code does that it invokes undefined behavior.  The compiler (especially at high optimization levels) might then compile your code into a binary that doesn't do what you want.  You can think of it as the compiler first optimizes your code, then replaces `memcpy()` with an assignment.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you for writing out this answer! Very much appreciated. It helped me understand it better. BR

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from @[Mr. R.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r) above, my approach for converting a 3 byte big endian unsigned char array within a structure to a little endian unsigned int...

```
struct mystruct {
  int stuff;
  int stuff2;
  unsigned char x[3]    // big endian
} 
mystruct z;
unsigned int y  // little endian

memcpy(&y, z->x, 3);
y=be32toh(y<<8);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's the same endianess a union would the best option.

```
union
{
    uint32_t u32;
    float flt;  
    uin8_T bytes[4];

} converter;
```

// Use of the above union

```
converter.bytes = your_byte_array;
uint32_t u32_output = converter.u32;
float float_output = converter.flt;
```