# Is it safe to compare an (uint32_t) with an hard-coded value?

Tags: c, uint32-t

I need to do bitewise operations on 32bit integers (that indeed [represent chars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7059314/2227298), but whatever).

Is the following kind of code safe?

```
uint32_t input;
input = ...;

if(input & 0x03000000) {
    output  = 0x40000000;
    output |= (input & 0xFC000000) >> 2;
```

I mean, in the "if" statement, I am doing a bitwise operation on, on the left side, a uint32_t, and on the right side... I don't know!

So do you know the type and size (by that I mean on how much bytes is it stored) of hard-coded "0x03000000" ?

Is it possible that some systems consider 0x03000000 as an int and hence code it only on 2 bytes, which would be catastrophic?

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: The right side is promoted to the smallest integer type it fits in (or `int` if it would be shorter than `int`), so the comparison is safe.

Comment: 1. You can always cast it to what you need: `(uint32_t)0x03000000`. 2. You should make these `#define` for clarity and re-use. You can add the cast too: `#define MYBITS (uint32_t)0x03000000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the following kind of code safe?

Yes, it is.

> So do you know the type and size (by that I mean on how much bytes is it stored) of hard-coded "0x03000000" ?

`0x03000000` is `int` on a system with `32-bit` `int` and `long` on a system with `16-bit` `int`.

(As `uint32_t` is present here I assume two's complement and `CHAR_BIT` of `8`. Also I don't know any system with `16-bit` `int` and `64-bit` `long`.)

> Is it possible that some systems consider 0x03000000 as an int and hence code it only on 2 bytes, which would be catastrophic?

See above on a `16-bit` `int` system, `0x03000000` is a `long` and is `32-bit`. An hexadecimal constant in C is the first type in which it can be represented: 
`int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long`

Comment: OK but what if I use 0x00000001 instead? On 16-bit system it will be represented as a 16-bit int. Then I will do a bitewise operation between a 32-bit uint32_t and a 16-bit 0x00000001. Will that throw an error or is it OK?

Comment: `0x00000001` is guaranteed to be an `int`. In the bitwise expression  with an `uint32_t` the constant will be promoted to `uint32_t`, so no problem.

Comment: @ouah: I think on a platform where `int` is 64 bit wide, both sides would be converted to `int`.